# unable to load view which was returned by the service

Tags: jquery, spring

I have a service with return type ModelAndView which is called from jquery. The problem is that i am unable to load view whic was returned by the service

@Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveOrUpdateGroupFeature", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public@ResponseBody ModelAndView saveOrUpdateGroupFeature(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request,GroupFeatureBean groupFeatureBean) throws ParseException {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("group/listGroups");
    // code here

    return mv;
}
```

Service call in JSP PaGE uisng JQUERY

```
$.ajax({
    url:'<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Admin/saveOrUpdateGroupFeature',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { gridData: celValue},
    dataType: 'json',
});
```

Now I need to display an error message if my condition failures in one page and if success the message should display in another page.. How can i handle it???

Answer (score 0):

According to jquery docs: [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
.done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
});
```

If you want to check the actuall value, you should do a check in done and see if the returned result contains like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Admin/saveOrUpdateGroupFeature',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { gridData: celValue},
    dataType: 'json',
})
.done(function(data) {
    if(data) {
        //Do something if exists
    } else {
        //Do something if not
    }
});
```